# Count of items in column A not in column B (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns of numbers in Google sheets. I’m trying to find a formula to give me a count of items in column A that are not in column B. The numbers in the columns are descending and unique in each column but can be duplicated across columns. The columns can also have different amounts of items in them.

Column A has 5 4 3 1

Column B has 4 2 1

The answer is this case would be 2 as the numbers 5 and 3 in column A are not in column B.

I’ve tried using sum, if and countif but can’t come up with a solution. Also not sure if this would be an array formula or not.

Comment: Try these methods found here
https://spreadsheetpoint.com/find-unique-values-google-sheets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a helper column you can use `reduce` and `lambda` functions.

`=reduce(0, A:A, LAMBDA(prev, a_value, prev + if(not(a_value = ""), iferror(min(0, match(a_value, B:B, false)), 1), 0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Fill column c with this formula:

```
=iferror(min(0,match(A1,B:B,false)),1)
```

If A1 is in column b the match function will return an value, which is then reduced to 0 by the min function. Otherwise match will return an error, and the iferror will return 1.

Then you just need to sum column c.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not appear to work. I get 0 0 0 1 in column C for a total of 1 (should be 2). Also, I prefer a solution without a helper column.

Comment: Apologies, change the true to false. I'll update the answer